OnChange + submit functionを使って、別フレームの情報をアップデートする方法
phpで簡単なWebsiteを作成したいです。
現在困っている点は、OnChange + submit functionを使って、別フレームの情報をアップデートする方法で、ここで質問させていただきます。
先にトイモデルを示して、その後に困っている箇所を示します。
トイモデルとして３つのphpを作成しました。
以下のように設定しております。
<framework_test.php>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<frameset cols='15%,*' rows='*'>
  <frame src="framework_test1.php" name='menu'>
  <frame src="framework_test2.php" name='naiyo'>
</frameset>

</html>

<framework_test1.php>
<html>
    test1
    menu
    <br>

    <form action="framework_test2.php" method="POST">
        <!-- <select name="myselect" id="myselect" onchange="parent.naiyo.window.location.href += '?workno='+this.value; this.form.submit()"> -->
        <select name="myselect" id="myselect" onchange="parent.naiyo.window.location.href = 'framework_test2.php'; this.form.submit()">
            <option value="1">One</option>
            <option value="2">Two</option>
            <option value="3">Three</option>
            <option value="4">Four</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</html>

<framework_test2.php>
<html>
    test2
    naiyo

    <?php
        print ($_POST['myselect']);
    ?>
    
</html>

現状では、framework_test1(menu)にあるselectを選択しても、framework_test2(naiyo)にその選択した番号を示さず、そのままframework_test1に表示してしまいます。framework_test1での選択をframework_test2で表示したいのですが、方法がわからず困っています。ご教授頂けると幸いです。よろしくお願いいたします。

自己解決しました。
メモ用に解決方法を記載しておきます。
方法は<framework_test1.php>の内容を変えるだけでした。
<html>
    test1
    menu
    <br>

    <form action="framework_test2.php" method="POST" **target="naiyo"**>
        <select name="myselect" id="myselect" **onchange="this.form.submit()"**>
            <option value="1">One</option>
            <option value="2">Two</option>
            <option value="3">Three</option>
            <option value="4">Four</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</html>

基本的にはformの中にtargetを記載するだけでした。
このサイトの回答を参考にしました。
